# Avoid R output leaking into LaTeX with ggnet

Tags: r, knitr

Please consider the following MWE which I compile into a .tex document via `knitr`

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

<<echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE>>=
library(igraph)
library(GGally)
library(network)
library(sna)

# Set up data
set.seed(123)
g <- barabasi.game(1000)

# Plot data
ggnet(g, weight.method = "indegree")

@


\end{document}
```

which inserts

```
\begin{verbatim}
## 1000 nodes, weighted by indegree 
## 
##    id indegree outdegree freeman
## 4   4       47         1      48
## 12 12       37         1      38
## 3   3       34         1      35
## 13 13       32         1      33
## 1   1       23         0      23
## 11 11       19         1      20
\end{verbatim}
```

in my .tex.

How could I control it?

Comment: looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24949113/avoid-r-output-leaking-into-latex-with-ggnet

Comment: @Yihui, yes but it seems I can't ask to close it as duplicate since are on a different sites...

Comment: No worries. Let's leave it to people who can do it. I cannot do it, either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `results="hide"` to the chunk options. See the [documentation](http://yihui.name/knitr/options).

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results="hide">>=
library(igraph)
library(GGally)
library(network)
library(sna)

# Set up data
set.seed(123)
g <- barabasi.game(1000)

# Plot data
ggnet(g, weight.method = "indegree")

@

\end{document}
```

[image: Result picture]